# Random Alphabetical String Added to URL

Tags: php, http, routing

I originally asked this question over at Stack Overflow, but someone there suggested asking here because it might be possible that something malicious may be causing the following issue:

Users have recently been having trouble accessing my website recently because random 5 letter alphabetical strings are being added to the end of the url after the user enters my domain on the address bar or clicks on a link to my website. It doesn't happen every time, it happens randomly.

Users enter:

https://www.example.com
After pressing enter the browser tries to visit:

https://www.example.com/oWLTm/
Could this be a problem with Google Analytics? Could it be a problem with routing? I'm at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

More info:

Hosted on: Heroku (but I have had the same problem locally)

Language: PHP

Framework: CodeIgniter

Analytics: Google

CDN: CloudFlare

Comment: Looks like some kind of redirect. Have you checked the site's default file (maybe an index.php)?

Comment: [Do you use godaddy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46307518)

Comment: @AndrolGenhald I purchased my domain through godaddy, but I use Cloudflare for my DNS. Is this a common problem with godaddy?

Comment: @user138172 this has been asked here before, see the link Androl gave you